# How to search for time in Excel?

Tags: excel, full-text-search, formula

Suppose if I have "30/06/2021 12:05 PM" in a particular cell having a paste as value like this "44377.50366". Is it possible to search and find values like "30/06/2021 12:05 PM" in a cell through any formulas? If i short the time from "30/06/2021 12:05" PM to "12:05 pm" would it be easier to search for?

I tried using Vlookup for this, but unless I enter the 30/06/2021 12:05 PM and search it dosent search for the time 12:05 pm. in the table.

Comment: How you using `VLOOKUP()`? If you pass `"30/06/2021 12:05 PM"` as string then it will not work. Make sure this is true `date/time` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty is that although excel may *show* the values as long date, short date or just time, the actual value it's storing doesn't change.

I assume you wish to search for this time no matter what date is stored in the cell. For this you will need to use the `MOD()` function.
`=MOD(A1, 1)` will return the Time value from cell `A1` regardless of the date value.

If you have a range A1:A10 that you wish to search containing the DateTime values, in a different range (say B1:B10) use the function to put just the times in without the dates, then search that second range instead for the time values.